# CSS pseudo class selector :first - What is it? I found in sample code and can't find documentation on it

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

In some [sample code here at w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_ullifirst) the selector is:
ul li:first

I can't seem to find documentation on this usage of **:first** 
Here it makes only "Coffee" hide() and not "Coffee 2" as well.
I'm brand new to jQuery, so perhaps it has some as yet unrevealed meaning there.
[code screenshot from Tryit Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts4ZZ.png)

Comment: It's a jquery selector that's seem be to similar to `:first-child` - https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Comment: This is the third result from `google css :first` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first

Comment: it selects first among the jqeury collection

Comment: Thank you Ori Drori. It is a deprecated jquery selector. Preferred method is filter with .first() and that's all I saw in docs.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the comments answer the question fairly; but I would like to weigh in on one point raised by Ori Drori.
While the `:first` selector is similar to `:first-child`, there is an inherent difference.

Let us use the very example linked in the question:

```
<p>List 1:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>List 2:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>
<button>Click me</button>
```

When we run the following script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("ul li:first").hide();
  });
});
```

The item `<li>Coffee</li>` present in List 1 gets hidden. However the one present in List 2 stays visible.

If instead, we were to use the selector `:first-child` in the following manner:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("ul li:first-child").hide();
  });
});
```

Both the `<li>Coffee</li>` elements get hidden.

This is because the `:first` selector accesses the first DOM node that satisfies the conditions given, i.e. the first element selected under the given selector.

Whereas the `:first-child` selector is more specific and selects the node that is the first child of it's parent element.
As we can see, the second `<li>Coffee</li>` element is the first child of the list `<ul>List 2</ul>`
Hence both the elements get hidden if we use the second script.

Hope this clarifies your doubts. A better practice, in my opinion, would be to use a class or id and be more specific while differentiating those elements whenever you need to.